# Invalid JSON : Invisible Chars?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using JSON to go between PHP and Javascript/Jquery... and for some reason the data I am pulling out of a MSSQL table is intermittenly making my JSON invalid. I cannot see any reason why this should be invalid... and the same set of data works fine for OTHER entries. I've tried different char encodings... I have tried using htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() and certian entries still render the JSON invalid.

Here is an example of invalid JSON

```
{"TASK": "test","TYPE": "Other Issue","SUBTYPE": "","CATEGORY": "","REQUEST": "Mat Gilbert","OPENDATE": "Dec 8 2010  5:12PM","PRIORITY": "2 - Low","DUEDATE": "","DESCRIPT": "12/8/2010 12:12 PM Eastern Standard Time - scldom\mgilbert test\n","STATUS": "","RESPONS": ""}
```

When I use jsonlint... it tells me the following:

syntax error, unexpected TINVALID at line 10

Line 10 is the "DESCRIPT" field.

I'm totally lost as to why this is invalid JSON. Please help.

Comment: You are using json_encode() and not trying to hand craft the json yourself, correct?

Comment: htmlentities/htmlspecialchars are for encoding HTML text... JSON has absolutely nothign to do with HTML - you have to generate valid Javascript text, which is a whole different ballgame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape this slash `scldom\mgilbert` like so `scldom\\mgilbert`.

To save yourself future trouble generating proper JSON, you can use PHP's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Comment: Thank you so much for this... unfortunately the build of PHP I'm using (4.3.9) does not have that function, and the people who maintain the environment don't want to upgrade to 5.x. I wrote my own function to fudge exporting the JSON data format... I will include this right away!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
scldom\mgilbert
```

`\m` is invalid. Change it to `\\m`